# Check the status of a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to conduct an audit with if statement, though playlist contains the word 'http', `playlist should have value 'http: //*********/****.m3u` but if playlist does not contain the word 'http' then I would like to have the value `playlist '"file: ///" + playlist'`

```
def GETPLAYLIST(): 
    playlistset = int(addon.getSetting('playlistset')) + 1 
    playlist = addon.getSetting('playlist' + str(playlistset)) 
    if 'http' in 'playlist'
    else:
        playlistlist = "file:///" + playlist
    return playlist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invert your condition and do this way:

```
def GETPLAYLIST(): 
    playlistset = int(addon.getSetting('playlistset')) + 1 
    playlist = addon.getSetting('playlist' + str(playlistset)) 
    if not 'http' in playlist:
        playlist = "file:///" + playlist
    return playlist
```

Comment: ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
                                             - NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
                                            Error Type: <type 'exceptions.IndentationError'>
                                            Error Contents: ('expected an indented block', ('C:\\Users\\***\default.py', 126, 9, '    playlist = "file:///" + playlist\n'))   -->End of Python script error report<--

Comment: There is some error in the indentation, check if everything is right and consistent with your current code in the line with `playlist = "file:///" + playlist`

Comment: I double-checked, I had made a syntax error, it works, great. Thank you